# PowerMockito.whenNew() is not getting mocked and original method is called with junit 5

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5, powermockito, junit-jupiter

I am writing Junit **jupiter** test for project. I am trying to mock new instance creation using mock.
but instead of getting mock object i am getting actual object

please see my code below

Main java class

```
public class TestSubjectClass {
    public String doSomething() {
        Integer number = new Integer(1);
        return internalLogic(number.toString());
}
    }
```

My test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TestSubjectClass.class)
class TestSubjectClassTest {
    @Test
    public void mockNewObjectCreation() throws Exception {
        TestSubjectClass testedClass = new TestSubjectClass();
        Integer mockedValue = new Integer(5);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Integer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockedValue);
        String output = testedClass.doSomething();
        assertThat(output, CoreMatchers.containsString("Here is an input: 5"));
  }
 }
```

My pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

When i run junit 5 test the actual mocking of new instance is not happening . Any clue what i did wrong

*Java.lang.assertionerror:
Expected: a string containing "Here is an input 5"
but was "Here is an input 1"*

Error:

[image]

Comment: Note that you should never call `new Integer`, _period_, regardless of testability issues.

Comment: Update :When I change to Junit 4 test class , mocking works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't analyze or make any comment about this particular test, but note that up to this point there is no PowerMock support for JUnit 5:

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/830

So you might want to consider using JUnit 4 for this.